Should I always include initialization layers in my Neural Network initialization part?
I saw someone's code contain using Xavier this way (in the follow), the code is using to predict house pricing data with 1400 rows and 300 variables(80, before one-hot-encoding). I searched its description, and it says to prevent gradient vanishing or exploding, and to accelerate convergence. This seems to be all beneficial, so should I always include Xavier initialization in my code? Or when should I not include Xavier? TIA
class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net,self).__init__()
        self.hidden_layer1 = nn.Linear(331,1024)
        self.hidden_layer2 = nn.Linear(1024,1024)
        self.hidden_layer3 = nn.Linear(1024,1024)
        self.hidden_layer4 = nn.Linear(1024,1024)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(1024,1)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.2) 
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.hidden_layer1.weight)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.hidden_layer2.weight)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.hidden_layer3.weight)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.hidden_layer4.weight)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.output_layer.weight)

def forward(self,x):
    inputs = x
    layer1_out = torch.nn.functional.gelu(self.hidden_layer1(inputs))
    layer1_out = self.dropout(layer1_out)
    layer2_out = torch.nn.functional.gelu(self.hidden_layer2(layer1_out))
    layer2_out = self.dropout(layer2_out)
    layer3_out = torch.nn.functional.gelu(self.hidden_layer3(layer2_out))
    layer3_out = self.dropout(layer3_out)
    layer4_out = torch.nn.functional.gelu(self.hidden_layer4(layer3_out))
    layer4_out = self.dropout(layer4_out)
    output = torch.relu(self.output_layer(layer4_out))
    return output

I've been trying to learn deep learning, but I've never been clear about the importance of including initialization in neural networks.
